# Can't convert List of List<Object> (Room Database)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have inserted `ArrayList<GreetingModel>` to `Room Database`. Now I want to get `ArrayList<ArrayList<GreetingModel>>` from there. But my `TypeConverter` doesn't work.

Here is my TypeConverter

```
object ConvertersList {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String): ArrayList<ArrayList<GreetingModel>> {
        val listType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>() {

        }.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, listType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromArrayLisr(list: ArrayList<ArrayList<GreetingModel>>): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(list)
    }
}
```

Here is function `loadAllGreetingsList`

```
val allGreetingsList: LiveData<List<List<GreetingModel>>>
        get() = dataBase.greetingDao().loadAllGreetingsList()
```

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM greeting")
   abstract fun loadAllGreetingsList(): LiveData<List<List<GreetingModel>>>
```

Getting this

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<java.util.List<com.example.myapplication.models.GreetingModel>>>).
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<java.util.List<com.example.myapplication.models.GreetingModel>>> loadAllGreetingsList();
```

Comment: `List<List<>>` can't be manipulated, use `MutableList` or `ArrayList` for `loadAllGreetingsList()` method return type.

Comment: but I need `List<List<GreetingModel>`. I need to set list depends on there position. Is  Mutable list will help?

Comment: I inserted several `<List<GreetingModel>>` and I need to get the list of those lists

Comment: Yes, it will help. Basically `List` in Kotlin don't have method to perform operations, but `MutableList` have those things. check the collections diagram from here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html#collection-types

Comment: I just try to change it to MutableList of List<GreetingModel> but getting the same error. Can you, please, help to change my code correctly?

Comment: Please post your entity class.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/U55Jw3X-jBISDw

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<GreetingModel>>` Why?

Comment: I inserted several ArrayList<GreetingModel> and want to get the list of inserted lists